# ¿ Cómo ingresar un dato vacío a mysql, a través de php?

Tags: php, html, mysql

necesito que me puedan ayudar con lo de php se refiere.
Tengo campos en html que son opcionales,a modo de ejemplo tengo esto.

```html
<form>
   <div class="form-row">1
       <div col>
       <input type="text" placeholder="ingrese nombre" name="nombre">
       </div>
       <div col>
       <input type="text" placeholder="ingrese apellido" name="apellido">
       </div>
       <div col>
       <input type="text" placeholder="ingrese edad" name="edad">
       </div>
       <div col>
       <input type="text" placeholder="ingrese direccion" name="direccion">
       </div>
       <div col>
       <input type="text" placeholder="ingrese telefono" name="telefono">    
       </div>
    </div>
   <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form
```

El tema de todo esto, es que algunos campos no quiero que sean necesariamente requeridos. 
cuando hago el llamado en php:

```html
<?php
      require(db.php);
      $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
      $apellido = $_POST['apellido'];
      $edad = $_POST['edad'];
       $direccion = $_POST['apellido'];
       $correo = $_POST['apellido'];

        $sql= INSERT.... (el llamado)
 ?>
```

¿Dónde debo colocar la condicion en php, para permitir que cuando obtenga los datos vacios, (a modo de ej: correo), lo tome como $correo= '', y pueda enviarlo de todas maneras a la base de datos a través de la consulta, y que en la base de datos, la columna correo aparezca ese campo vacío?..

Comment: tendrías que verificar si el campo esta definido y dar un default `$correo = ! empty( $_POST['correo'] ) ? $_POST['correo']:'' ;`

Comment: lo hice pero aún no me inserta todo los valores.

Comment: yo usaria isset an lugar de  empty. Y para que sean null tienes que hacer lo siguiente. $correo = isset($_POST['correo']) ? $_POST['correo'] : null;

Comment: Los campos vacíos de un formulario se envían como cadenas vacías en las variables `$_POST` asociadas, por lo que en principio no es necesaria ninguna modificación en el código.

Answer (score 0):

Usando PDO seria de esta manera:

```
<?php

require(db.php);

$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$apellido = $_POST['apellido'];
$edad = $_POST['edad'];
$direccion = $_POST['direccion'];
$correo = $_POST['correo'];

$db = dataBase();
$query = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO users (nombre, apellido, edad, direccion, correo) VALUES (:nombre, :apellido, :edad, :direccion, :correo)');
$query->execute([
    'nombre' => $nombre ?? '',
    'apellido' => $apellido ?? '',
    'edad' => $edad ?? '',
    'direccion' => $direccion ?? '',
    'correo' => $correo ?? ''
]);

?>
```

1. Se crea una conexión a la base de datos
2. Se prepara la consulta (INSERT)
3. Se ejecuta la consulta pasando los valores que se van a insertar

Si te fijas cada variable en `execute()` la escribo seguido de `?? ''`, esto valida si la variable a la izquierda es nula, si lo es, asigna el valor que coloques a la derecha, en este caso sería un string vacio:  `''`

En el archivo `db.php` iría el siguiente código:

```
<?php

function dataBase()
{
    $connection = "mysql:host=HOST;port=PORT;dbname=DB_NAME";
    return new PDO($connection, 'root', '');
}

?>
```

**Nota:** La ventaja de usar **PDO** es que ya no tienes que preocuparte por la limpieza de los datos que el usuario introduzca, pues el se encarga de hacer todo lo necesario para proteger la base de datos de **sql injection**.